# Insert a value into a column by a condition Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out how to insert a value according to the condition in another column. It is necessary to insert the value from the second file according to the condition, the beginning is the value "01", and the end is the value "01"-1. The beginning always begins with "01".
Examples of input data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'N1': ['01', '02','03','01','02','01','02','03','04'],
'N2':['', '','','','','','','','']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'N1': [ 'PALA A','PALA B','PALA C']})
```

Result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
'N1': ['01', '02','03','01','02','01','02','03','04'],
'N2':['PALA A', 'PALA A','PALA A','PALA B','PALA B','PALA C','PALA C','PALA C','PALA C']})
```

Desired result on the screenshot, any help or links to similar examples or documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df1['N2'] = df2.loc[(df1['N1'] == '01').cumsum() - 1].set_axis(df1.index, axis=0)
```

**Result:**

```py
   N1      N2
0  01  PALA A
1  02  PALA A
2  03  PALA A
3  01  PALA B
4  02  PALA B
5  01  PALA C
6  02  PALA C
7  03  PALA C
8  04  PALA C
```

Comment: raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]" - I got this error when using your method, maybe you know how to fix it?

Comment: @ValerieOputin that means your `df2.index` doesn’t have one of the keys: 0, 1 or 2

Comment: df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  - i used the following code to fix the error now i have the following error: raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key. But the length there will never match, maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: try adding `, 'N1'` to `loc` like this:  `df2.loc[(df1['N1'] == '01').cumsum() - 1, 'N1']... ` - this will select only the column `N1` in `df2`